# Search outside of the wordpress “loop”

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a blog using only Wordpress's backend. I have found functions to get latest posts (wp_get_recent_posts) and all the required data I need. I do this by including wp-load so I have access to WP's functions.

However I cannot find anything that allows me to perform a search outside of Wordpress's theming loops as I have for the rest of the data.

I was hoping there was a search function where I can pass it a search query that could be in title, body content or tag name.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious in the documentation, there seems to be a function for everything else I need outside of WP's "loop".

Comment: Just curious about the reason why you would not use the theming functions and load WP by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that work for you?

```
// query for a given term ("search_term")
$search_query = new WP_Query();
$search_posts = $search_query->query('s=search_term');
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wp-hackers/JqpLnU-91-k)

Answer (score 2):

Answered by sanchothefat:

You can use get_posts() with a search parameter:

```
$results = get_posts( array( 's' => 'search term' ) );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74763/search-outside-of-the-loop/74766#74766